# Does accessing a user's iTunes library on an iOS device require permission?

Tags: ios, ios6, itunes, ios7, mpmediaquery

If I wanted to get access to the metadata on the music stored in a user's iTunes library via `MPMediaQuery`, would that require the user to give their permission, in a similar way apps request access to Photos, Contacts, etc.?

I've never seen an app ask for access to my iTunes library, but I'm wondering whether that's because it's implicit, or it's impossible. I'd perhaps like to do some scanning and make some assumptions about the user's musical taste based on the information, preferably without them knowing or needing to consent to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the song list does not require a permission (iOS6 and iOS7).

According to Apple ([link for **iOS6**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html)), *Data Privacy* section,

> In addition to location data, the system ***now asks the user’s
>   permission*** before allowing third-party apps to access certain user
>   data, including: Contacts, Calendars, Reminders, Photo Library.

This policy has not changed for the [newly-released **iOS7**](https://www.apple.com/ios/what-is/):

> iOS is designed to put your privacy first. For example, if an app
>   wants your location information or data from Calendar, Contacts,
>   Reminders, or Photos, it needs your permission first.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thankyou. Apologies, I could've looked that one up really, couldn't I?

Comment: the question has already been answered, but is of interest now since Apple could have changed their data protection policy for iOS7 - that's why I added the iOS6/7 tags.